# What is the best practice to handle non-datetime timestamp column within pandas dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, time-series, missing-data, pyspark-pandas

Let's say I have the following [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) dataframe with a *non-standard* timestamp column without datetime format. Due to I need to include a new column and convert it into an 24hourly-based timestamp for time-series visualizing matter by:

```py
df['timestamp(24hrs)'] = round(df['timestamp(sec)']/24*3600)
```

and get this:

```
+----------------+----+-----+
|timestamp(24hrs)|User|count|
+----------------+----+-----+
|0.0             |U100|435  |
|1.0             |U100|1091 |
|2.0             |U100|992  |
|3.0             |U100|980  |
|4.0             |U100|288  |
|8.0             |U100|260  |
|9.0             |U100|879  |
|10.0            |U100|875  |
|11.0            |U100|911  |
|13.0            |U100|628  |
|14.0            |U100|642  |
|16.0            |U100|631  |
|17.0            |U100|233  |
 ...               ...  ...
|267.0           |U100|1056 |
|269.0           |U100|878  |
|270.0           |U100|256  |
+----------------+----+-----+
```

Now I noticed that some records' timestamps are missing, and I need to impute those missing data:

- `timestamp(24hrs)` in continuous order
- `count` value by `0`

Expected output:

```
+----------------+----+-----+
|timestamp(24hrs)|User|count|
+----------------+----+-----+
|0.0             |U100|435  |
|1.0             |U100|1091 |
|2.0             |U100|992  |
|3.0             |U100|980  |
|4.0             |U100|288  |
|5.0             |U100|0    |
|6.0             |U100|0    |
|7.0             |U100|0    |
|8.0             |U100|260  |
|9.0             |U100|879  |
|10.0            |U100|875  |
|11.0            |U100|911  |
|12.0            |U100|0    |
|13.0            |U100|628  |
|14.0            |U100|642  |
|15.0            |U100|0    |
|16.0            |U100|631  |
|17.0            |U100|233  |
 ...               ...  ...
|267.0           |U100|1056 |
|268.0           |U100|0    |
|269.0           |U100|878  |
|270.0           |U100|256  |
+----------------+----+-----+
```

Any idea how can I do this? Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69963120/10452700) over *standard* timestamp, I can imagine I need to create a new column `timestamp(24hrs)` from the start and end of the previous one and do left `join()` & `crossJoin()` but I couldn't manage it yet.

I've tried the following unsuccessfully:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

all_dates_df = df.selectExpr(
    "sequence(min(timestamp(24hrs)), max(timestamp(24hrs)), interval 1 hour) as hour"
).select(F.explode("timestamp(24hrs)").alias("timestamp(24hrs)"))

all_dates_df.show()

result_df = all_dates_df.crossJoin(
    df.select("UserName").distinct()
).join(
    df, 
    ["count", "timestamp(24hrs)"],
    "left"
).fillna(0)

result_df.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sequence` function is available for integer. It doesn't work for double type so it requires to cast to integer then cast back to double (if you want to retain as double).

```
df_seq = (df.withColumn('time_int', F.col('timestamp(24hrs)').cast(IntegerType()))
          .select(F.explode(F.sequence(F.min('time_int'), F.max('time_int'))).alias('timestamp(24hrs)'))
          .select(F.col('timestamp(24hrs)').cast(DoubleType())))

df = (df_seq.crossJoin(df.select("User").distinct())
      .join(df, on=['User', 'timestamp(24hrs)'], how='left')
      .fillna(0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have 2 questions: 1- what if I just have `timestamp(24hrs)` and `count` columns (without `User` column) then how would the proposed solution look like? (here, they so call it the [look-up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74490625/10452700) process)  2- Is it possible to directly use a fixed integer number for an endpoint like `.select(F.explode(F.sequence(F.min('time_int'), 270)))`?

Comment: 1. you can skip the `crossJoin` 2. Yes but you need to wrap with `F.lit` for the constant value.

Comment: About Q2, I used `.select(F.explode(F.sequence(F.lit(0), F.lit(273))).alias('timestamp(24hrs)'))` but it strangely appends the dataset several times!! Maybe due to omitting `crossJoin()` but I include `.dropDuplicates(['timestamp(24hrs)'])` and
      `.orderBy('timestamp(24hrs)', ascending=True))` to ensure that we remove duplications and fix the order for visualizations issues.

Comment: Duplicates probably comes from your original data(`sequence` won't generate duplicates), and in that case, it is usually better to `dropDuplicates` before `join`.